# How To Invoke Rest Api from with Basic Authentication From SOA?

Tags: oracle, basic-authentication, soa

I want to invoke REST API from SOA with Basic Authentication. 
I did all configurations but it does not work.
How and where to set basic authentication username and password for the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure and attach this policy for the endpoint you are calling:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/owsm/OWSMS/owsm-predefined-policies.htm#OWSMS5467

Also see:
http://www.ateam-oracle.com/working-with-owsm-policies-part-1-of-some/